# Convert number sequence to Parent/Child hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq, csv, hierarchical-data

I'm loading a CSV file into my program which is passed from our legacy ERP System. The CSV contains [multi-level bill of materials (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials) data, that I will ultimately need to strip down and send each unique BOM off for processing. Currently, I'm struggling as record does not contain a parentID, instead relying on the order of the record to define any sort of parent/child relationship. 
The only thing I have to go on is the Level and SubLevel are laid out in a set sequence

- Level 0 is the root and can contain 1 or more Level1
- Level 1 is the child of 0 and could contain 0 or more Level2
- Level 2 is the child of 1 and could contain 0 or more Level1
- etc...

This is an example of the data which I've abbreviated for simplicity:

```
+---------------------------------+  
¦ UniquePartID ¦ Level ¦ SubLevel ¦  
¦--------------+-------+----------¦  
¦ 05468        ¦ 0     ¦ 0        ¦  
¦ 12420        ¦ 1     ¦ 1        ¦  
¦ 08186        ¦ 2     ¦ 1        ¦  
¦ 03926        ¦ 3     ¦ 1        ¦  
¦ 93650        ¦ 2     ¦ 2        ¦  
¦ 07642        ¦ 3     ¦ 1        ¦  
¦ 16569        ¦ 2     ¦ 3        ¦  
¦ 49397        ¦ 1     ¦ 2        ¦  
¦ 93093        ¦ 1     ¦ 3        ¦  
¦ 36250        ¦ 2     ¦ 1        ¦  
+---------------------------------+
```

And displayed hierarchically, this is how it would look:

```
                            0
            ------------------------
            |           |         | 
            1           1         1 
        ----------              ----
        |    |   |              |   
        2    2   2              2   
        -    -
        |    |
        3    3
```

I have loaded the CSV data into a class representation, but cannot figure an way to reliably identify a parent child relationship using the Level/Sublevel and the order of the file as my reference

Does anyone have any advice I could use?

Comment: Ahh tricky problem, I am stumped too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly easy:

```
class Node {
  public int UniquePartID { get; private set; }
  public int Level { get; private set; }
  public int SubLevel { get; private set; }
  public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }
  public Node Parent { get; set; }
  public Node(int uniquePartID, int level, int subLevel) {
    UniquePartID = uniquePartID;
    Level = level;
    SubLevel = subLevel;
    Children = new List<Node>();
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return Level.ToString();
  }
}
```

Fill with dummy data:

```
  var nodes = new List<Node> {
    new Node(05468, 0, 0),
    new Node(12420, 1, 1),  
    new Node(08186, 2, 1),  
    new Node(03926, 3, 1),  
    new Node(93650, 2, 2),  
    new Node(07642, 3, 1),  
    new Node(16569, 2, 3),  
    new Node(49397, 1, 2),  
    new Node(93093, 1, 3),  
    new Node(36250, 2, 1)
  };
```

Actual code:

```
var parent = nodes[0];
for (var i = 1; i < nodes.Count; i++) {
  var node = nodes[i];
  while (node.Level <= parent.Level) {
    parent = parent.Parent;
  }
  parent.Children.Add(node);
  node.Parent = parent;
  parent = node;
}
var root = nodes[0];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for Ondrej, Top man, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just store the last node of each level. If an entry occurs insert it in the stored (last) node of the current level minus 1 and insert it as the sublevel-th child. The inserted node is then again stored as the last node of its level. This should do the trick. Here is an example:

```
public class Entry
{
    public Entry(int id, int lvl, int sublvl)
    {
        UniquePartID = id;
        Level = lvl;
        SubLevel = sublvl;
    }

    public int UniquePartID;
    public int Level;
    public int SubLevel;
}

public class Node
{
    public int UniquePartID;
    public Node Parent = null;
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
}

public List<Node> LastLayerNodes = new List<Node>();

public Node BuildHierarchy(List<Entry> entries)
{
    Node root = null;

    foreach (Entry entry in entries)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.UniquePartID = entry.UniquePartID;

        if (entry.Level == 0)
        {
            root = node;
            LastLayerNodes.Add(root);
        }
        else
        {
            node.Parent = LastLayerNodes[entry.Level - 1];
            node.Parent.Children.Add(node);

            if (LastLayerNodes.Count <= entry.Level)
                LastLayerNodes.Add(node);
            else
                LastLayerNodes[entry.Level] = node;
        }
    }

    return root;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>
{
    new Entry(05468, 0, 0),
    new Entry(12420, 1, 1),
    new Entry(08186, 2, 1),
    new Entry(03926, 3, 1),
    new Entry(93650, 2, 2),
    new Entry(07642, 3, 1),
    new Entry(16569, 2, 3),
    new Entry(49397, 1, 2),
    new Entry(93093, 1, 3),
    new Entry(36250, 2, 1)
};

Node node = BuildHierarchy(entries);
```